# gRPC connection refused

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I have a code which is working just fine as localhost on port 5000 but when I use it client and server side on VPS the gRPC is refused my connection.

Server Side :

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITaskService, TaskService>();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AgentServiceMappings).Assembly);

builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAll", x =>
{
    x.AllowAnyOrigin();
    x.AllowAnyMethod();
    x.AllowAnyHeader();
    x.WithExposedHeaders("Grpc-Status", "Grpc-Message", "Grpc-Encoding", "Grpc-Accept-Encoding");
}));

builder.Services.AddGrpc();

builder.Services.AddHostedService<ExpiryTimeService>();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(options => options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());

app.UseGrpcWeb();

app.MapGrpcService<AgentService>().EnableGrpcWeb();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");

AgentService.StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

app.Run();
```

and this is Client Side :

```
public AdminService()
    {
        _channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/", new GrpcChannelOptions {
            HttpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(new HttpClientHandler())
        });
        _client = new AgentClient(_channel);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know if you can use all ports on your VPS? Is there a default firewall configured?

Comment: I literally disabled firewall but still nothing.

Comment: Can you check if you're listening on all interfaces or only localhost? (e.g. running netstat whilst your application is running on your VPS)

Comment: The app console said it listen to http://localhost:500  but the netstat say it listen to [::1]:5000

Comment: IIRC [::1] is the IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1. Which means your application is only listening on the loopback interface (= localhost). You need to check how to configure your application to listen on a specific network interface (or all of them)

Comment: I would use this syntax instead, you miss UseRouting  and Use EndPoints : 

    app.UseGrpcWeb(); // Must be added between UseRouting and UseEndpoints

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>().EnableGrpcWeb();
    });

Take a look at the doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/grpc/grpcweb?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @BouamK with the minimal api these are added automatically.

Comment: This may help https://andrewlock.net/why-isnt-my-aspnetcore-app-in-docker-working/

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your gRPC server is correctly configured to bind to the network interface on your VPS, specifically listening on the external IP address of your VPS. To achieve this, modify the following line in your server-side code
`app.Run();` to

```
app.Run(host: "0.0.0.0");
```

By using this configuration, your server will bind to all available network interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using port 5000 try port 50055

Had a similar issue with "regular" ports not working in production, while in production only port 50055 worked.

One more check to start with is to use curl or netcat to verify the server port is accessible from the client (not blocked):

client-prompt) `curl server-ip:50055`